# mysql query to get not repeated data and multiple where statements

Tags: mysql

I have some trouble creating a query that should have two AND statements in WHERE.

Example table:

```
type_id       type
00034         1
00035         2
00035         3
00036         2
00037         3
```

I'm looking to get the type_id that doesn't have a repeated id and the type is not 1 or 3. The expected result is 00036. But is not working:

```
SELECT type_id
FROM test
WHERE type_title !=1
GROUP BY type_id
HAVING count(type_id) = 1
```

Result is:

```
00036
00037
```

How do I make to get only 00036?

Best regards & nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that table name is "test_table", then following query will return what you need:

```
select t1.type_id
from test_table t1
join test_table t2 on t1.type_id = t2.type_id
where t2.type not in(1,3)
group by t1.type_id
having count(t1.type_id) = 1;
```

Comment: Clever. You use the first table to group off of, but the second table to limit the type ids. I never thought of doing it that way.

Comment: This one suits me best. Thanks all for the help. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

This solves the first part of the problem...

```
  SELECT x.*
    FROM test x 
   WHERE x.type NOT IN(1,3)
```

...and this solves the second part...

```
    LEFT
    JOIN test y
      ON y.type <> x.type
     AND y.type_id = x.type_id 
   WHERE y.type_id IS NULL;
```

...Putting it together looks like this...

```
  SELECT x.*
    FROM test x
    LEFT
    JOIN test y
      ON y.type <> x.type
     AND y.type_id = x.type_id
   WHERE x.type NOT IN(1,3)
     AND y.type_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Using AND instead of IN for the first part: `WHERE x.type <> 1 AND x.type <> 3`

Answer (score 0):

One method is to first get a list of all the records that don't have duplicate type_id's. Once you have that settled, it's an easy task to eliminate the other things such as type. This should give you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT test_outer.type_id FROM test AS test_outer

WHERE test_outer.type_id NOT IN(

    SELECT type_id FROM test
    WHERE type_id IN (
    SELECT type_id FROM test GROUP BY type_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1)

)

AND test_outer.type <> 1  
AND test_outer.type <> 3;
```

Looking at this from inside out we first check for any records that have a duplicate. Then we use that to get all records that have the same type_id as the duplicate (which includes the duplicate record we found). Then we get all records that don't have those type_id's, and we limit on type.

Best of luck.